# How could I reformat this data from many rows to many columns

Tags: excel, csv

Ive got a bunch of data in the form of https://i.stack.imgur.com/aFx9K.jpg.
I want a way to get it it to this form https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rc3ry.jpg without moving it manually.

I would prefer to use excel but I can do whatever. Any ideas?

Comment: That's a super user question: [support.office.com](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/transpose-rotate-data-from-rows-to-columns-or-vice-versa-3419f2e3-beab-4318-aae5-d0f862209744) as it's only about how to use a not programming tool. I will recommend reading [ask] and [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Key word you could have use to find this information on any search engines are: "pivot table", "rotate table", "Row as column", "Transpose", "switch column with row". And the mandatory term "Excel".

Comment: @xdtTransform the raw data are not arranged in a way that the OP can directly transpose it.. the OP need to deal with that 1st..

Comment: @p._phidot_, what is the issue? Just Close of topics, migrate so we can close with the adequat dupe: https://superuser.com/questions/1122833/how-to-transpose-groups-of-rows-to-columns. Yes I know that my previous comment are not enought to find the exact solution. The keyword missing was "Group".

Comment: its not a clear dupe.. this OP data structure is different.. || Dear Tom, you may please close this question here and post this question at superuser.com instead. stackoverflow.com is for mainly meant for programming question. [Info](https://stackexchange.com/sites#technology-traffic)

Comment: @p._phidot_, I have to disagree with you The Duplicate solution is valid and work. Having data with different name doesnt change what a pivot is. Was able to reproduce The expected result without using my keyboard. Pretty good sign that insert pivot table and a copy past is the solution;

Comment: I agree to disagree. /(^-^)

Comment: @xdtTransform Thanks for the advice of asking SU. I wasn't sure which would be better but as I didn't know if it was possible to do in excel I asked here incase someone knew how to do it with a script. What would be the correct protocol for migrating to superuser.com considering that there is an answer?

Comment: for the "protocol for migrating.." :  if it was from the original OP, just close the question and create a new one. Else, if it was from the community, a vote/flag action is needed to migrate a question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use for this in Excel Pivot Tables. It does exactly what you need.

Original data (My numbers are random, not same as yours):

[image]

And after inserting a Pivot Table, I get this:
[image]

Check:

> **[Pivot Tables](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/create-a-pivottable-to-analyze-worksheet-data-a9a84538-bfe9-40a9-a8e9-f99134456576)**